# can't declare url and path variables in useRouteMatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, ecmascript-6, react-router

Now i do so:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let r = useRouteMatch();
    this.path = r.path;
    this.url = r.url;
}
```

but this does not work and throws errors: url is not defined, if i use them in render()
This code is indicated in the documentation:

```
let {path, url} = useRouteMatch();
```

It works for functional programming, not for class. How to declare these variables in this as one line? Or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React hooks **only** work in functional components. You'll have to either directly render the component under the `Route`'s `component`, `children`, or `render` prop, or decorate it with the `withRouter` HOC and pull them from the `match` prop.

> You’ll have access to match objects in various places:
>
> - Route component as `this.props.match`
> - Route render as `({ match }) => ()`
> - Route children as `({ match }) => ()`
> - withRouter as `this.props.match`

```
const { match: { path, url } } = this.props;
```

[`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter)
[`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/match)

Answer (score 0):

The `useRouteMatch()` function is actually a React custom **hook**. Hooks will only work with functional components and hence you cannot use this with class components. You can read more about what hooks are how to use them [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).